# Is line an ex command in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim and I saw the following response in a [vimgolf](http://www.vimgolf.com/) challenge:

```
:%s/\d\d/\=line('.')*10/<CR>ZZ
```

Where does the "=line('.')" come from?  I've never seen it on any of the vim cheat sheets I've looked at.

Comment: When you don't know something, try `:help something` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:help line`.

`line` is a VIM function. `line('.')` returns the cursor position (line number).

Try this in VIM:

```
 :echo line('.')
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about :help